# AngularJS SPA edit button function

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS, currently I am trying to create a spa for tracking expenses as a simple project but I have some problems with my code.

I managed to do the most of the function but I got stuck at the edit button and edit function. I am trying to make an inline edit function because I already have a form input.

Here is the html and js code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Expenses Tracker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <span class="navbar-brand"><img src="logo.png" class="brand" height="40" />
                 Simple Expenses App Tracker</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="main" ng-app="myList" ng-controller="myListController">

        <img src="logo.png" class="logo">
        
    <form ng-submit="newItem()" class="form">
        <input required type="number" placeholder="Amount" ng-model="amount">
        <input required type="text" placeholder="Description" ng-model="description">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success">
    </form>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item in items">
                <span  class="pull-left"> {{item.amount}} den.</span> {{item.description}}
                <span class="buttons">
                    <input type="button" value="Edit" class="btn btn-primary" >
                    <input type="button" ng-click="deleteItem($index)" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger">
                </span>
            </li>
            <br>
            <li><span class="total">{{totalPrice()}} den.</span> <span class="expense"> Total Expenses</span></li>
        </ul>
        
    </div>


    <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
var myApp = angular.module("myList", []);

myApp.controller("myListController", function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [];

    $scope.newItem = function() {
        $scope.items.push({description:$scope.description, amount: $scope.amount});
        $scope.description = '';
        $scope.amount = 0
    };

    $scope.deleteItem = function(index) {
        $scope.items.splice(index, 1);
    }

    $scope.totalPrice = function() {
        var total = 0;
        for(count=0; count<$scope.items.length;count++){
            total += $scope.items[count].amount;
        }
        return total;
    };

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like:

```js
$scope.editItem = function(index) {
    $scope.amount = $scope.items[index].amount;
    $scope.description = $scope.items[index].description;
    $scope.deleteItem(index);
}
```

I also recommend you read this book:
https://www.newline.co/ng-book/modern-ng1/

Try to move away from using $scope for bindings and user components. Unless you really don't care where this project goes.